# Adding header 'Authorization' in Angular

Tags: angular, token, interceptor

I want to set header for every request.

I am using request.clone for setting header in Angular 7.2.14

```
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpEvent, HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpResponse, HttpErrorResponse, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {


    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {        
        const token=localStorage.getItem('token');
        console.log(token);
        request.clone({ headers: request.headers.set('Authorization', token) });    
        return next.handle(request)
    }

}
```

I am not getting error but I can see Authorization header

Comment: You call request.clone() but you ignore the result, which is the new, cloned request, with the header.

Comment: tried but getting error on console , blocked by CORS policy

Comment: And that's a completely different problem. Google for CORS. The response to the pre-flight request probably doesn't allow for the Authoriation header. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: Getting same error.

Comment: Getting same error when doing what? Remember: I can't see your screen.

Comment: After adding this code :
request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        }
    });

    return next.handle(request).pipe(delay(1200));

Comment: @ApoorvSrivastava what error are you getting is it a CORS , make sure if you api needs just `${token}` or `Bearer ${token}` CORS is handled in the backend . So if you have set the header properly the rest of it should be handled by the backend team

Comment: And I already told you that this error is a completely different problem. Google for CORS. The response to the pre-flight request probably doesn't allow for the Authoriation header. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS. Fixing the frontend code won't magically fix your server configuration.

Comment: Okay I got it..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are returning old request not cloned one.

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        }
    });

    return next.handle(request);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`request.clone()` returns an object, doesn't mutate the origin.

try pass `request.clone()` as parameter.

```ts
    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {        
        const token=localStorage.getItem('token');
        console.log(token);    
        return next.handle(request.clone({ headers: request.headers.set('Authorization', token) });)
    }
```

Comment: Tried but getting blocked by CORS policy